# Eloquent get only one column as an array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to get only one column as one dimentional array in laravel 5.2 using eloquent?

I have tried:

```
$array = Word_relation::select('word_two')->where('word_one', $word_id)->get()->toArray();
```

but this one gives it as 2 dimentional array like:

```
array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["word_one"]=>
        int(2)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["word_one"]=>
        int(3)
      }
    }
```

but I want to get it as:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>2
    [1]=>3
}
```

Answer (score 281, accepted):

You can use the [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-pluck) method:

```php
Word_relation::where('word_one', $word_id)->pluck('word_two')->toArray();
```

For more info on what methods are available for using with collection, you can you can check out the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#available-methods).

Comment: Thanks, that was the function I saw somewhere but didn't find it anymore, also for the record, for the answer to be presice, then maybe add ->toArray() since it returns colletion at the moment and select can be left out from the query for laravel 5.2 at least.

Comment: True about the `select` being redundant, but I don't see a problem with having a collection as a result, because a collection is just a _fancy_ array that can be iterated over the same as an array. I rarely use arrays instead of collections since the memory footprint is generally not a problem, and collections can be easily cast to arrays where needed because they implement the [`toArray`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L961-L967) method. However, for consistency with your question, I  modified the answer to do convert the result.

Comment: At the moment I am quite new to laravel and eloquent, so I needed these as array of numbers to later merge the array with similar one and use it in another query

Comment: While a `Collection` also has a `pluck()` method - What you are using is a method of [`QueryBuilder`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results).

Comment: why toArray()? only pluck is good enough i think. Oh!! got your point. sorry for pointing this.

Answer (score 19):

That can be done in short as:

```
Model::pluck('column')
```

where model is the Model such as `User` model & column as column name like `id`

if you do

```
User::pluck('id') // [1,2,3, ...]
```

& of course you can have any other clauses like `where` clause before pluck

Answer (score 16):

If you receive multiple entries the correct method is called [lists](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_lists).

```php
    Word_relation::select('word_two')->where('word_one', $word_id)->lists('word_one')->toArray();
```

Comment: Awesome! The `lists()` works fine by it self. Thank you.

Comment: Boom! This works perfectly. But don't need to use toArray() function because lists() returns an array.

Comment: `lists()` is deprecated in Laravel Ver.5.2 and later, where `pluck()` as in the tagged answer is the way.

Answer (score 8):

I came across this question and thought I would clarify that the lists() method of a eloquent builder object was depreciated in Laravel 5.2 and replaced with pluck().

```
// <= Laravel 5.1
Word_relation::where('word_one', $word_id)->lists('word_one')->toArray();
// >= Laravel 5.2
Word_relation::where('word_one', $word_id)->pluck('word_one')->toArray();
```

These methods can also be called on a Collection for example

```
// <= Laravel 5.1
  $collection = Word_relation::where('word_one', $word_id)->get();
  $array = $collection->lists('word_one');

// >= Laravel 5.2
  $collection = Word_relation::where('word_one', $word_id)->get();
  $array = $collection->pluck('word_one');
```

Answer (score -4):

In Laravel 5.2, you can retrieve a single column as a one-dimensional array from a database using Eloquent by using the pluck method. The pluck method retrieves a collection of a single column's values. Here's an example of how you can use it:

1- Basic Usage of **pluck** Method:

```
$columnValues = YourModel::pluck('columnName')->all();
```

In this example, replace YourModel with the name of your Eloquent model and columnName with the name of the column you want to retrieve. The all() method is used to convert the collection into a plain PHP array.

2- Applying Conditions:
You can also apply conditions before plucking the values. For instance, if you want to get values of a column where another column meets a certain condition, you can do:

```
$columnValues = YourModel::where('anotherColumnName', 'value')->pluck('columnName')->all();
```

This will first filter the rows where anotherColumnName equals value and then pluck the values of columnName.

Comment: Can you please explain that.

Comment: As far as I am aware doing `Model::get(['ColumnName'])->toArray();` is equivalent of doing `Model::select('ColumnName')->get()->toArray()` which results in a multi dimensional array.