# select a specfic column from a inner joined table in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I need all columns from invoice,invoice_details table but I want to get only one column (column name: `amount`) from my payment table. What will be my query for it? here is my controller.

```
$all_invoice = DB::table('invoice')
        ->join('invoice_details', 'invoice.invoice_id', '=', 'invoice_details.invoice_id')
        ->join('payment', 'invoice.invoice_id', '=', 'payment.invoice_id')
        ->where('invoice.client_id', 7)
        ->orderBy('invoice.invoice_id', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

Comment: then just use select, DB::table('invoice')->select("payment.amount")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eloquent get only one column as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912265/eloquent-get-only-one-column-as-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

This very simple you need to add  select clause in query like this.

$all_invoice = DB::table('invoice')->select(['invoice.*', 'payment.amount'])
                                  ->join('invoice_details','invoice.invoice_id','=','invoice_details.invoice_id')
                                ->join('payment','invoice.invoice_id','=','payment.invoice_id')->where('invoice.client_id',7)->orderBy('invoice.invoice_id','DESC')->get();

If have still query the see the laravel docs in select option in query.

Comment: it only gets the amount column.but I need all columns from invoice,invoice_details table but only

Answer (score 0):

Just using select

```
$all_invoice = DB::table('invoice')
       ->join('invoice_details', 'invoice.invoice_id','=','invoice_details.invoice_id')
       ->join('payment', 'invoice.invoice_id', '=', 'payment.invoice_id')
       ->where('invoice.client_id', 7)
       ->select('payment.amount')
       ->orderBy('invoice.invoice_id', 'DESC')
       ->get();
```

Comment: it only gets the amount column.but I need all columns from invoice,invoice_details table but only amount from payment table

Comment: ->select('invoice.*','invoice_details.*','payment.amount')    If you have the same column names, you should give a different name using 'as'